# PHP insert filter and print it out on images

Tags: php, html, database, image, post

I have this annoying problem where i try to add a filter to an image that I posted. The image filters loads in with a css file: CSSgram.css. The correct filter (option html) is given in the select field and it gets it and saves it into the database correctly. However i fail to print out the right filter on the image because there are errors in the HTML class where php variable should be added.

Code snippets below:

```js
<?php
//tweet.PHP
  class Tweet extends User{
 protected $message;

  public function __construct($pdo){
  $this->pdo = $pdo;
  // added new code for PHP 7
  $this->message  = new Message($this->pdo);
 }

      public function tweets($user_id, $num){
      //select alles uit de db
     $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `tweets` LEFT JOIN `users` ON `tweetBy` = `user_id` WHERE `tweetBy` = :user_id AND `retweetID` = '0' OR `tweetBy` = `user_id` AND `retweetBy` != :user_id AND `tweetBy` IN (SELECT `receiver` FROM `follow` WHERE `sender` =:user_id) ORDER BY `tweetID` DESC LIMIT :num");
     $stmt->bindParam(":user_id", $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
     $stmt->bindParam(":num", $num, PDO::PARAM_INT);
     $stmt->execute();
     $tweets = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

     //display de geposte info
     foreach ($tweets as $tweet) {
       $likes = $this->likes($user_id, $tweet->tweetID);
       $retweet = $this->checkRetweet($tweet->tweetID, $user_id);
       $user = $this->userData($tweet->retweetBy);
            var_dump($tweet);
       //insert html van de tweets
       echo '<div class="all-tweet">
         <div class="t-show-wrap">
          <div class="t-show-inner">
          '.(($retweet['retweetID'] === $tweet->retweetID OR $tweet->retweetID > 0) ? '
          <div class="t-show-banner">
           <div class="t-show-banner-inner">
            <span><i class="fa fa-retweet" aria-hidden="true"></i></span><span>'.$user->screenName.' Retweeted</span>
           </div>
          </div>'
           : '').'

           '.((!empty($tweet->retweetMsg) && $tweet->tweetID === $retweet['tweetID'] or $tweet->retweetID > 0) ? '<div class="t-show-head">
           <div class="t-show-popup" data-tweet="'.$tweet->tweetID.'">
             <div class="t-show-img">
             <img src="'.$user->profileImage.'"/>
            </div>
            <div class="t-s-head-content">
             <div class="t-h-c-name">
              <span><a href="'.$user->username.'">'.$user->screenName.'</a></span>
              <span>@'.$user->username.'</span>
              <span>'.$this->timeAgo($retweet['postedOn']).'</span>
             </div>
             <div class="t-h-c-dis">
              '.$this->getTweetLinks($tweet->retweetMsg).'
             </div>
            </div>
           </div>
           <div class="t-s-b-inner">
            <div class="t-s-b-inner-in">
             <div class="retweet-t-s-b-inner">
               '.((!empty($tweet->tweetImage)) ? '
              <div class="retweet-t-s-b-inner-left">
               <img src="'.$tweet->tweetImage.'" class="'.$tweet->filter.'" data-tweet="'.$tweet->tweetID.'"/>
              </div>' : '').'
              <div>
               <div class="t-h-c-name">
                <span><a href="'.$tweet->username.'">'.$tweet->screenName.'</a></span>
                <span>@'.$tweet->username.'</span>
                <span>'.$this->timeAgo($tweet->postedOn).'</span>
               </div>
               <div class="retweet-t-s-b-inner-right-text">
                '.$this->getTweetLinks($tweet->status).'
               </div>
              </div>
             </div>
            </div>
           </div>
           </div>' : '

          <div class="t-show-popup" data-tweet="'.$tweet->tweetID.'">
           <div class="t-show-head">
            <div class="t-show-img">
             <img src="'.$tweet->profileImage.'"/>
            </div>
            <div class="t-s-head-content">
             <div class="t-h-c-name">
              <span><a href="'.$tweet->username.'">'.$tweet->screenName.'</a></span>
              <span>@'.$tweet->username.'</span>
              <span>'.$this->timeAgo($tweet->postedOn).'</span>
             </div>
             <div class="t-h-c-dis">
              '.$this->getTweetLinks($tweet->status).'
             </div>
            </div>
           </div>'.
             ((!empty($tweet->tweetImage)) ?
            '<!--tweet show head end-->
                 <div class="t-show-body">
                   <div class="t-s-b-inner">
                    <div class="t-s-b-inner-in">
                      <img src="'.$tweet->tweetImage.'" class="" data-tweet="'.$tweet->tweetID.'"/>
                    </div>
                   </div>
                 </div>
                 <!--tweet show body end-->
             ' : '').'

          </div>').'
          <div class="t-show-footer">
           <div class="t-s-f-right">
            <ul>
             <li><button><i class="fa fa-share" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></li>
             <li>'.(($tweet->tweetID === $retweet['retweetID']) ?
              '<button class="retweeted" data-tweet="'.$tweet->tweetID.'" data-user="'.$tweet->tweetBy.'"><i class="fa fa-retweet" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="retweetsCount">'.$tweet->retweetCount.'</span></button>' :
              '<button class="retweet" data-tweet="'.$tweet->tweetID.'" data-user="'.$tweet->tweetBy.'"><i class="fa fa-retweet" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="retweetsCount">'.(($tweet->retweetCount > 0) ? $tweet->retweetCount : '').'</span></button>').'
             </li>
             <li>'.(($likes['likeOn'] === $tweet->tweetID) ?
              '<button class="unlike-btn" data-tweet="'.$tweet->tweetID.'" data-user="'.$tweet->tweetBy.'"><i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="likesCounter">'.$tweet->likesCount.'</span></button>' :
              '<button class="like-btn" data-tweet="'.$tweet->tweetID.'" data-user="'.$tweet->tweetBy.'"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="likesCounter">'.(($tweet->likesCount > 0) ? $tweet->likesCount : '' ).'</span></button>').'
             </li>
                  
                   '.(($tweet->tweetBy === $user_id) ? '
                      <li>
              <a href="#" class="more"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
              <ul>
                <li><label class="deleteTweet" data-tweet="'.$tweet->tweetID.'">Delete Tweet</label></li>
              </ul>
             </li>' : '').'

            </ul>
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
         </div>
         </div>';
     }
 }
  
 public function getUserTweets($user_id){
  $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `tweets` LEFT JOIN `users` ON `tweetBy` = `user_id` WHERE `tweetBy` = :user_id AND `retweetID` = '0' OR `retweetBy` = :user_id ORDER BY `tweetID` DESC");
  $stmt->bindParam(":user_id", $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt->execute();
  return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
 }
 
 public function addLike($user_id, $tweet_id, $get_id){
  $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("UPDATE `tweets` SET `likesCount` = `likesCount`+1 WHERE `tweetID` = :tweet_id");
  $stmt->bindParam(":tweet_id", $tweet_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt->execute();

  $this->create('likes', array('likeBy' => $user_id, 'likeOn' => $tweet_id));
 
  if($get_id != $user_id){
   //this fixed php 7 error for non static methods
   $this->message->sendNotification($get_id, $user_id, $tweet_id, 'like');
  }
 }

 public function unLike($user_id, $tweet_id, $get_id){
  $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("UPDATE `tweets` SET `likesCount` = `likesCount`-1 WHERE `tweetID` = :tweet_id");
  $stmt->bindParam(":tweet_id", $tweet_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt->execute();

  $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM `likes` WHERE `likeBy` = :user_id and `likeOn` = :tweet_id");
  $stmt->bindParam(":user_id", $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt->bindParam(":tweet_id", $tweet_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt->execute(); 
 }

 public function likes($user_id, $tweet_id){
  $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `likes` WHERE `likeBy` = :user_id AND `likeOn` = :tweet_id");
  $stmt->bindParam(":user_id", $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt->bindParam(":tweet_id", $tweet_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt->execute();
  return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 }
 
 public function getTrendByHash($hashtag){
  $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `trends` WHERE `hashtag` LIKE :hashtag LIMIT 5");
  $stmt->bindValue(":hashtag", $hashtag.'%');
  $stmt->execute();
  return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
 }

 public function getMension($mension){
  $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT `user_id`,`username`,`screenName`,`profileImage` FROM `users` WHERE `username` LIKE :mension OR `screenName` LIKE :mension LIMIT 5");
  $stmt->bindValue("mension", $mension.'%');
  $stmt->execute();
  return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

 }

 public function addTrend($hashtag){
  preg_match_all("/#+([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/i", $hashtag, $matches);
  if($matches){
   $result = array_values($matches[1]);
  }
  $sql = "INSERT INTO `trends` (`hashtag`, `createdOn`) VALUES (:hashtag, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";
  foreach ($result as $trend) {
   if($stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql)){
    $stmt->execute(array(':hashtag' => $trend));
   }
  }
 }

 public function addMention($status,$user_id, $tweet_id){
  if(preg_match_all("/@+([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/i", $status, $matches)){
   if($matches){
    $result = array_values($matches[1]);
   }
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = :mention";
   foreach ($result as $trend) {
    if($stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql)){
     $stmt->execute(array(':mention' => $trend));
     $data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }
   }

   if($data->user_id != $user_id){
    //This fixed PHP 7 error for non static methods
    $this->message->sendNotification($data->user_id, $user_id, $tweet_id, 'mention');
   }
  }
 }

 public function getTweetLinks($tweet){
  $tweet = preg_replace("/(https?:\/\/)([\w]+.)([\w\.]+)/", "<a href='$0' target='_blink'>$0</a>", $tweet);
  $tweet = preg_replace("/#([\w]+)/", "<a href='http://localhost/twitter/hashtag/$1'>$0</a>", $tweet);  
  $tweet = preg_replace("/@([\w]+)/", "<a href='http://localhost/twitter/$1'>$0</a>", $tweet);
  return $tweet;  
 }

 public function getPopupTweet($tweet_id){
  $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `tweets`,`users` WHERE `tweetID` = :tweet_id AND `tweetBy` = `user_id`");
  $stmt->bindParam(":tweet_id", $tweet_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt->execute();
  return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
 }

 public function retweet($tweet_id, $user_id, $get_id, $comment){
  $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("UPDATE `tweets` SET `retweetCount` = `retweetCount`+1 WHERE `tweetID` = :tweet_id AND `tweetBy` = :get_id");
  $stmt->bindParam(":tweet_id", $tweet_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt->bindParam(":get_id", $get_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt->execute();

  $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `tweets` (`status`,`tweetBy`,`retweetID`,`retweetBy`,`tweetImage`,`postedOn`,`likesCount`,`retweetCount`,`retweetMsg`) SELECT `status`,`tweetBy`,`tweetID`,:user_id,`tweetImage`,`postedOn`,`likesCount`,`retweetCount`,:retweetMsg FROM `tweets` WHERE `tweetID` = :tweet_id");
  $stmt->bindParam(":user_id", $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt->bindParam(":retweetMsg", $comment, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(":tweet_id", $tweet_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt->execute();

  //This fixed PHP 7 error for non static methods
  $this->message->sendNotification($get_id, $user_id, $tweet_id, 'retweet');

  }

 public function checkRetweet($tweet_id, $user_id){
  $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `tweets` WHERE `retweetID` = :tweet_id AND `retweetBy` = :user_id or `tweetID` = :tweet_id and `retweetBy` = :user_id");
  $stmt->bindParam(":tweet_id", $tweet_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt->bindParam(":user_id", $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt->execute();
  return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 }

 public function tweetPopup($tweet_id){
  $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `tweets`,`users` WHERE `tweetID` = :tweet_id and `user_id` = `tweetBy`");
  $stmt->bindParam(":tweet_id", $tweet_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt->execute();
  return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
 }

 public function comments($tweet_id){
  $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `comments` LEFT JOIN `users` ON `commentBy` = `user_id` WHERE `commentOn` = :tweet_id");
  $stmt->bindParam(":tweet_id", $tweet_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt->execute();
  return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
 }

 public function countTweets($user_id){
  $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT COUNT(`tweetID`) AS `totalTweets` FROM `tweets` WHERE `tweetBy` = :user_id AND `retweetID` = '0' OR `retweetBy` = :user_id");
  $stmt->bindParam(":user_id", $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt->execute();
  $count = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
  echo $count->totalTweets;
 }

 public function countLikes($user_id){
  $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT COUNT(`likeID`) AS `totalLikes` FROM `likes` WHERE `likeBy` = :user_id");
  $stmt->bindParam(":user_id", $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt->execute();
  $count = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
  echo $count->totalLikes;
 } 

 public function trends(){
  $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT *, COUNT(`tweetID`) AS `tweetsCount` FROM `trends` INNER JOIN `tweets` ON `status` LIKE CONCAT('%#',`hashtag`,'%') OR `retweetMsg` LIKE CONCAT('%#',`hashtag`,'%') GROUP BY `hashtag` ORDER BY `tweetID` LIMIT 10");
  $stmt->execute(); 
  $trends = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
  echo '<div class="trend-wrapper"><div class="trend-inner"><div class="trend-title"><h3>Trends</h3></div><!-- trend title end-->';
  foreach ($trends as $trend) {
   echo '<div class="trend-body">
     <div class="trend-body-content">
      <div class="trend-link">
       <a href="'.BASE_URL.'hashtag/'.$trend->hashtag.'">#'.$trend->hashtag.'</a>
      </div>
      <div class="trend-tweets">
       '.$trend->tweetsCount.' <span>tweets</span>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>';
  }
  echo '</div></div>';  
 } 

 public function getTweetsByHash($hashtag){
  $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `tweets` LEFT JOIN `users` ON `tweetBy` = `user_id` WHERE `status` LIKE :hashtag OR `retweetMsg` LIKE :hashtag");
  $stmt->bindValue(":hashtag", '%#'.$hashtag.'%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->execute();
  return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
 }

 public function getUsersByHash($hashtag){
  $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM `tweets` INNER JOIN `users` ON `tweetBy` = `user_id` WHERE `status` LIKE :hashtag OR `retweetMsg` LIKE :hashtag GROUP BY `user_id`");
  $stmt->bindValue(":hashtag", '%#'.$hashtag.'%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->execute();
  return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
 }
}
?>
```

```css
<?php
//HOME.php
  include 'core/init.php';
  $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
  $user = $getFromU->userData($user_id);
  $notify  = $getFromM->getNotificationCount($user_id);


  if(isset($_POST['tweet'])){
    $status = $getFromU->checkinput($_POST['status']);
    $tweetImage = '';
    $filter = $_POST['filter'];  //filter select


    if(!empty($status) or !empty($_FILES['file']['name'][0])){
      if(!empty($_FILES['file']['name'][0])){

          //voeg image pad toe
        $tweetImage = $getFromU->uploadImage($_FILES['file']);
      }
        // check textarea lengte
      if(strlen($status) > 140){
        $error = "The text of your tweet is too long";
      }
      //insert data naar de tweets tabel via create method via een array
         $tweet_id = $getFromU->create('tweets', array('status' => $status, 'tweetBy' => $user_id, 'tweetImage' => $tweetImage,
             'postedOn' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), 'filter' => $filter ));

      preg_match_all("/#+([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/i", $status, $hashtag);


       if(!empty($hashtag)){
        $getFromT->addTrend($status);
      }
      $getFromT->addMention($status, $user_id, $tweet_id);
    }else{
      $error = "Type or choose image to post";
    }


  }

?><!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
 <head>
  <title>Home - Tweety</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.css"/>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style-complete.css"/>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/cssgram.css"/>
       <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <!--Helvetica Neue-->
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<!-- header wrapper -->
<div class="header-wrapper">

<div class="nav-container">
 <!-- Nav -->
 <div class="nav">

  <div class="nav-left">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="home.php"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>Home</a></li>
            <?php if($getFromU->loggedIn()=== true){?>
     <li><a href="notification.php"><i class="fa fa-bell" aria-hidden="true"></i>Notifications<span id="notificaiton"><?php if($notify->totalN > 0){echo '<span class="span-i">'.$notify->totalN.'</span>';}?></span></a></li>
     <li id="messagePopup"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>Messages<span id="messages"><?php if($notify->totalM > 0){echo '<span class="span-i">'.$notify->totalM.'</span>';}?></span></li>
    <?php }?>

   </ul>
  </div><!-- nav left ends-->

  <div class="nav-right">
   <ul>
    <li>
     <input type="text" placeholder="Search" class= "search"/>
     <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
     <div class="search-result">
     </div>
    </li>

    <li class="hover"><label class="drop-label" for="drop-wrap1"><img src="<?php echo $user->profileImage; ?>"/></label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="drop-wrap1">
    <div class="drop-wrap">
     <div class="drop-inner">
      <ul>
       <li><a href="profile.php">Profile</a></li>
       <li><a href="account.php">Settings</a></li>
       <li><a href="logout.php">Log out</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </div>
    </li>
    <li><label class="addTweetBtn">Tweet</label></li>
   </ul>
  </div><!-- nav right ends-->

 </div><!-- nav ends -->

</div><!-- nav container ends -->

</div><!-- header wrapper end -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/search.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/hashtag.js"></script>

<!---Inner wrapper-->
<div class="inner-wrapper">
<div class="in-wrapper">
 <div class="in-full-wrap">
  <div class="in-left">
   <div class="in-left-wrap">
  <div class="info-box">
   <div class="info-inner">
    <div class="info-in-head">
     <!-- PROFILE-COVER-IMAGE -->
     <img src="<?php echo $user->profileCover; ?>"/>
    </div><!-- info in head end -->
    <div class="info-in-body">
     <div class="in-b-box">
      <div class="in-b-img">
      <!-- PROFILE-IMAGE -->
       <img src="<?php echo $user->profileImage; ?>"/>
      </div>
     </div><!--  in b box end-->
     <div class="info-body-name">
      <div class="in-b-name">
       <div><a href="<?php echo $user->username; ?>"><?php echo $user->screenName; ?></a></div>
       <span><small><a href="<?php echo $user->username; ?>">@<?php echo $user->username; ?></a></small></span>
      </div><!-- in b name end-->
     </div><!-- info body name end-->
    </div><!-- info in body end-->
    <div class="info-in-footer">
     <div class="number-wrapper">
      <div class="num-box">
       <div class="num-head">
        TWEETS
       </div>
       <div class="num-body">
        <?php $getFromT->countTweets($user_id); ?>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="num-box">
       <div class="num-head">
        FOLLOWING
       </div>
       <div class="num-body">
        <span class="count-following"><?php echo $user->following; ?></span>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="num-box">
       <div class="num-head">
        FOLLOWERS
       </div>
       <div class="num-body">
        <span class="count-followers"><?php echo $user->followers; ?></span>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div><!-- mumber wrapper-->
    </div><!-- info in footer -->
   </div><!-- info inner end -->
  </div><!-- info box end-->

 <!--==TRENDS==-->
   <?php $getFromT->trends(); ?>
  <!--==TRENDS==-->

 </div><!-- in left wrap-->
  </div><!-- in left end-->
  <div class="in-center">
   <div class="in-center-wrap">
    <!--TWEET WRAPPER-->
    <div class="tweet-wrap">
     <div class="tweet-inner">
       <div class="tweet-h-left">
        <div class="tweet-h-img">
        <!-- PROFILE-IMAGE -->
         <img src="<?php echo $user->profileImage; ?>"/>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="tweet-body">
       <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <textarea class="status"  maxlength="141" name="status" placeholder="Type Something here!" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
         <div class="hash-box">
         <ul>
           </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
       <div class="tweet-footer">
        <div class="t-fo-left">
         <ul>
          <input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>
          <li><label for="file"><i class="fa fa-camera" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
          <span class="tweet-error"><?php if(isset($error)){echo $error;}else if(isset($imgError)){echo $imgError;} ?></span>


                                        <?php echo "You have selected :" .$filter; // Displaying Selected Value ?>
                                        <select name="filter">
                                            <option value="_1977">1977</option>
                                            <option value="aden">Aden</option>
                                            <option value="brannan">Brannan</option>
                                            <option value="brooklyn">Brooklyn</option>
                                            <option value="clarendon">Clarendon</option>
                                            <option value="earlybird">Earlybird</option>
                                            <option value="gingham">Gingham</option>
                                            <option value="hudson">Hudson</option>
                                            <option value="inkwell">Inkwell</option>
                                            <option value="kelvin">Kelvin</option>
                                            <option value="lark">Lark</option>
                                            <option value="lo-Fi">Lo-Fi</option>
                                            <option value="maven">Maven</option>
                                            <option value="mayfair">Mayfair</option>
                                            <option value="moon">Moon</option>
                                            <option value="nashville">Nashville</option>
                                            <option value="perpetua">Perpetua</option>
                                            <option value="reyes">Reyes</option>
                                            <option value="rise">Rise</option>
                                            <option value="slumber">Slumber</option>
                                            <option value="stinson">Stinson</option>
                                            <option value="toaster">Toaster</option>
                                            <option value="valencia">Valencia</option>
                                            <option value="walden">Walden</option>
                                            <option value="willow">Willow</option>
                                            <option value="xpro2">X-pro II</option>
                                        </select>

          </li>
         </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="t-fo-right">
         <span id="count">140</span>
         <input type="submit" name="tweet" value="tweet"/>
       </form>
        </div>
       </div>
     </div>
    </div><!--TWEET WRAP END-->


    <!--Tweet SHOW WRAPPER-->
     <div class="tweets">
        <?php $getFromT->tweets($user_id, 10); ?>
      </div>
     <!--TWEETS SHOW WRAPPER-->
 
       <div class="loading-div">
        <img id="loader" src="assets/images/loading.svg" style="display: none;"/>
       </div>
    <div class="popupTweet"></div>
    <!--Tweet END WRAPER-->
          <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/like.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/retweet.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/popuptweets.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/delete.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/comment.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/popupForm.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/fetch.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/messages.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/notification.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/postMessage.js"></script>

         
   </div><!-- in left wrap-->
  </div><!-- in center end -->

  <div class="in-right">
   <div class="in-right-wrap">

    <!--Who To Follow-->
     <?php $getFromF->whoToFollow($user_id, $user_id); ?>
        <!--Who To Follow-->

    </div><!-- in left wrap-->
     <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/follow.js"></script>
  </div><!-- in right end -->

 </div><!--in full wrap end-->
 </div><!-- in wrappper ends-->
</div><!-- inner wrapper ends-->
</div><!-- ends wrapper -->
</body>

</html>
```

```html
<?php 
//init.php!

 session_start();
 include 'database/connection.php';
 include 'classes/user.php';
 include 'classes/tweet.php';
 include 'classes/follow.php';
 include 'classes/message.php';
   global $pdo;

   $getFromU = new User($pdo);
   $getFromT = new Tweet($pdo);
    $getFromF = new Follow($pdo);
    $getFromM = new Message($pdo);
  
define('BASE_URL', 'http://localhost:8888/twitter/');
```

Comment: "there are errors in the HTML class where php variable should be added"  And what exactly are those errors?

Comment: @Patrick, [so] does not run `php` code, which means there's no point in turning the above code into a snippet.

Comment: yeah @PatrickQ i know but it's just to share my code and problem so

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I didn't make anything a snippet.  It already was.  I simply combined two block that should have been one.

Comment: The php doesn't add the right class so f.e Toaster to that image class field which is needed for show the filter on the image

Comment: @Patrick: my bad, I didn't actually look into what you did. Distortion, it would be much better if you restricted the snippet to the code that does not behave the way you want it and showing: the php code, the current output, the desired output.

Comment: The second block of code makes no sense to me. It's like the first 19 lines would be part of a variable or an echo statement and the string would be single quoted over multi lines. Yet the second part is like you broke out of PHP and typed html. Is this really the code you are using right now? Edit : @PatrickQ I've just noticed you made the edit. Still not sure if the two blocks make sense together...

Comment: You seem to add `$tweet->filter` as class but filter seems to be saved in `$filter` variable. What is in `$tweet->filter`?

Comment: @Lou I agree that they might not really make sense or belong together.  The first part is incomplete by itself though (ends in the middle of a ternary operator), so I'm not sure that they make much more sense on their own either.  I wouldn't necessarily object to an edit that splits them back apart.

Comment: If i put only $filter variable it says undefined, if i do it this way which still doesn't work, i dont get error @AndreiGheorghiu

Comment: @PatrickQ after that html echo block theres more public functions declared for other features

Comment: The `<select>` sent value is stored in `$filter`, not in `$tweet->filter`. We can't know what you're sending inside `$tweet` (your're not showing it).

Comment: @Distortion Can you provide an example of what you get in your class and a var_dump of $tweet?

Comment: foreach ($tweets as $tweet) {
       $likes = $this->likes($user_id, $tweet->tweetID);
       $retweet = $this->checkRetweet($tweet->tweetID, $user_id);
       $user = $this->userData($tweet->retweetBy);

       //insert html van de tweets
       echo '<div class="all-tweet">

Comment: @Lou Sure this is the var dump: object(stdClass)#12 (24) { ["tweetID"]=> string(2) "34" ["status"]=> string(0) "" ["tweetBy"]=> string(2) "39" ["retweetID"]=> string(1) "0" ["retweetBy"]=> string(1) "0" ["tweetImage"]=> string(20) "users/background.jpg" ["likesCount"]=> string(1) "0" ["retweetCount"]=> string(1) "0" ["postedOn"]=> string(19) "2018-05-11 15:01:25" ["filter"]=> string(7) "toaster" ["retweetMsg"]=> string(0) "" ["user_id"]=> string(2) "39" ["username"]=> string(0) "" ["full name"]=> string(0) "" ["email"]=> string(22) "thomaske33@hotmail.com" ["password"]=> string(60) "$2y$10$1f0

Comment: Basicly what's in the DB table tweets: it got fetched: $tweets = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

Comment: Undefined variable: filter, how do i fix this? if i put in $filter its the same

Comment: What is the relation of all this code?  Is this all in the same file?  If not, how exactly are they connected?

Comment: @PatrickQ 2 seperated files, one is the home.php and the other one tweet.php and it includes on top a init.php file in home file which has all the classes in it like also tweet (second block)

Comment: Please update your code to show `init.php` and the code in `home.php` that include this and make sure it is clear where this code is in relation to the code above.

Comment: @PatrickQ Done it above is init.php / home.php / tweet.php, hope this helps :/

Comment: @Distortion Have you had a chance to make the changes in my answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple ways to handle this.  I'm just going to show the one that's the simplest for me to write up.

To start, give `$filter` a default (empty) value if one hasn't been selected.

`$filter = (!empty($_POST['filter']) ? $_POST['filter'] : '');  //filter select`

Then, when you make the call to get and display the tweets, pass the selected filter value (if any).

`<?php $getFromT->tweets($user_id, 10, $filter); ?>`

Update `tweets.php` to accept the filter as a parameter on the `tweets()` function (I'm also giving it a default value in the function definition in case you are calling it from other places).

`public function tweets($user_id, $num, $filter = ''){`

Finally, use this passed in value as the class value

`<img src="'.$tweet->tweetImage.'" class="'.$filter.'" data-tweet="'.$tweet->tweetID.'"/>`

An alternative would be to create a new function in your `Tweet` class called something like `setFilter($filter)`.  You would then call that function in `main.php`, passing in the selected filter, and access it within your `Tweet` class as `$this->filter`.

Comment: Thanks for your help: now I got the following error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$getFromT' (T_VARIABLE) in home.php on line 242

Comment: <?php $getFromT->tweets($user_id, 10, $filter); ?> its this line

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: filter in C:\MAMP\htdocs\twitter_v2\home.php on line 240 ->most recent error. But in the var_dump / DB i can get the right filter

Comment: If line 242 is `<?php $getFromT->tweets($user_id, 10, $filter); ?>` (as you indicated in your comment above), then line 240 should be `<!--Tweet SHOW WRAPPER-->`  and that definitely wouldn't be throwing that error

Comment: line 242 is where the error is right now yep, my mistake. This one:  <?php $getFromT->tweets($user_id, 10, $filter); ?>

Comment: You're getting that when you first load the page, before you submit the filter selection, right?  If so, put this after line 6: `$filter = '';`

Comment: yes thank you now the error is gone but it still doesnt add up in my HTML class tag.

Comment: I must be misunderstanding what you're really trying to accomplish.  You're selecting a filter and then that filter gets applied to the tweets that get fetched, no?

Comment: Yep -> select a filter from select option html and pass it onto that img class in HTML with PHP

Comment: Few screens to visualize what i mean, Please take a look at: https://ibb.co/nFWeMJ
https://ibb.co/bYX8Fd
https://ibb.co/hb5vvd

Comment: on the third picture u can see that class is empty, that's the problem and I dont really know how to fix it atm

Comment: basicly giving that html a class filter to the uploaded image. @PatrickQ